# Change the colour of the list item in listview depending on the value in the list android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to change the colour of the list item in `ListView` in a fragment depending on the value of the item. any suggestions would be great. I've tried a few options with `getView()` but no luck.

```
String[] validvalues = new String[] {personalList, doctorsList,carerList,
    myMedList,mymedproblist,kinList,relyList,allergiesList
};

ArrayAdapter<String> files2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,validvalues);
View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.verify, container, false);

list.setAdapter(files2);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view2,int position, long id) {
        String str = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), position + " " + str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Something like if string.contains("!!") > set background colour to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ArrayAdapter, create a custom Adapter class (possibly derived from it). Then, in the getView() method, set the background color of the returned view. For example, just change the ArrayAdapter creation in your code with:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> files2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,validvalues)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View itemView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (getItem(position).contains("!!"))
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        return itemView;
    }
};
```

Comment: Updated with the condition you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own `Adapter`.

I would extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView()` so that it looks something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Note: you could get a LayoutInflater and inflate your own layout here instead
    // of calling through to super.
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    String content = getItem(position);
    if (content.equals("StringToLookFor") {
        row.setBackgroundColor(yourRowColor);
    } else {
        row.setBackgroundColor(yourOtherRowColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, im having a problem.. ive put that code at the bottom the class but it cant find the getItem ? if i put the code where my other adpater is it doesnt allow the method..

Comment: It sounds like you just put this method at the bottom of your `Fragment` class. It needs to go in an `ArrayAdapter` subclass, just like the other answers here described. That subclass can go at the bottom of your fragment if you want.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you must define your own custom adapter

```
 public class myadapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>
  {

    public myadapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return validvalues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // here you can  change color 
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.yourcustomlayout, null);
        }
        if (validvalues[position].equals( ""))
        v.setBackgroundColor(color)
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code, I gave u here an example with even and odd position ( u can change the condition on the position as u like )

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here is the implementation of MyListAdapter

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IArtVO> {

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<INoteVO> {

    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(context, R.layout.ifact1_help2, R.layout.ifact1_help1, liste);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return yourListe.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textViewRed, parent, false);
            itemView.setText(" your text");

        } else {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.textViewGreen, parent, false);
            itemView.setText(" your text");
        }
        return itemView;
    }

}
```

and here is the textViewRed.xml and green which u have to define on the directory layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:background="@color/red"
/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:background="@color/green"
/>
```